# How to handle to read a column and cast to Option[String] from postgre db which has null and string values in Scala 2?

Tags: string, scala, pattern-matching

I had a problem with null data coming from one of the postgre db tables.
In my situation, I have a column that is nullable which means it stores originally varchar data but has also null values for some rows. I read that column as Any data type inside Scala 2.

My first problem was using .toString function and I took Null Pointer Exception error of course.
Then, I decided to cast that column to Option[String], but I couldn,t write pattern matching code.

Here is my trial:

```
val deneme = null
val myOption: Option[String] = deneme match {
  case str: String => Option(str)
  case null => None
}
```

As a result, I am taking that error:

```
<console>:26: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : String
 required: Null
         case str: String => Option(str)
```

How can I come up with a solution for my case?

If know the root cause and solution, I will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need the pattern match, just `val safe = Option(unsafe)`, also why are you reading the data as `Any`? You should almost never ever have an `Any` in your **Scala** code. Are you connecting to the database from scratch? Why not use a library like **Skunk**, **Doobie**, **Slick**, **Quill**, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Null` is the universal subtype of reference types similarly to `Nothing`, which is the universal subtype of all types.

So when you initialize a variable with `null`, just declare the type

```
val deneme: String = null
```

Otherwise, the type of variable will be inferred `Null`.

So happened here. Then all patterns were erroneously checked to conform `Null`.

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/Null.html

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/Nothing.html